# Role to hostname mapping with Ansible Pull

Tags: ansible

I have used Ansible in the regular push-mode with an inventory where there are several groups. I have “workstations” and “servers” and some other stuff.

Now with `ansible-pull` I have rolled out a `cron` job to the “workstations” which pull a git repository and then apply the `localhost.yml` to themselves. This works fine, but I would like to have different roles mapped to the different groups.

My only idea is to roll out different `cron` jobs to the different machines and have a `workstations.yml` playbook and so on.

Is it sensible to let Ansible find out (with inventory or a variable) which group the host belongs to? I think one could define a dictionary of lists with the hostnames. And then I do this:

```
- role: workstation
  when: ansible_hostname in inventory['workstations']
- role: laptop
  when: ansible_hostname in inventory['laptops']
```

Is that a good solution or should I rather do something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `ansible-pull` appends `-l localhost,node-name,127.0.0.1` parameter when calling `ansible-playbook`.

This way you can have inventory:

```
[workstations]
node1
[laptops]
node2
```

and playbook `local.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - generic
- hosts: workstations
  roles:
    - workstation
- hosts: laptops
  roles:
    - laptop
```

Because of `-l` only `generic+laptops` play will be applied to `node2` and `generic+workstations` to `node1`. Plays not related to current node will be skipped with

> skipping: no hosts matched